# Add meta data to only one dimension of numpy.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, subclassing

I have several two-dimensional data sets as `numpy.array`. I subclassed `array` to add additional meta-data to every data set that I can access via `MyArray.MyAttribtue`.

My (very much shortened) code of my subclass looks like the following:

```
class MyArray(np.ndarray):
    _attributes = {"orig_file": None,
                   "protocol": None
                   # plus many more...
                  }

    _datatype = {'names': ['phase', 'mask'],
                 'formats': [np.float32, np.bool_]
                 # plus a few more...
                 }

    def __new__(cls, input_array, mask=None, **keypar):
        # cast to custom class
        obj = np.asarray(input_array, dtype=cls._datatype).view(cls)
        if mask is None:
            mask = True
        if input_array.dtype != cls._datatype:
            obj['mask'] = mask
        # add attributes
        for attr in keypar:
            if attr in cls._attributes:
                setattr(obj, attr, keypar[attr])
        for attr in cls._attributes:
            try:
                getattr(cls, attr)
            except AttributeError:
                setattr(cls, attr, cls._attributes[attr])
        # return new object
        return obj

    def __array_finalize__(self, obj):
        if obj is None:
            return
        for attr in self._attributes:
            setattr(self, attr, getattr(obj, attr, self._attributes[attr]))

    def __array_wrap__(self, obj, context=None):
        return obj.view(type(self))
```

Now I want to combine several of these data sets into a three-dimensional array while keeping the meta-data for every set individually.
I do not want to have a list of 2d-arrays, because I want to be able to perform array-routines in every direction (e.g. `MyArray.mean()` and similar stuff), which I altered in my subclass.

I suppose I could save the meta-data in a list inside the class and access it like `MyThreeDimArray.MyAttribute[0]`, but ideally, I would like to be able to access this data in a similar fashion as before, basically doing something like `MyThreeDimArray[0].MyAttribute`. Is there a way to achieve something like that?

Comment: I think you have to customize the `__getitem__` method, so that when you index the array, you get back another array of this class with the appropriate subset of the attributes list.

Comment: Can't you use `pandas` for this? Reinventing something like this is probably not very advised. Arrays with meta data is a pretty common requirement, and there are existing numpy friendly solutions for it.

Comment: @rth I guess I could use `pandas`, yes. But that would mean to reimplement a lot of stuff, so at this point I'd rather stay with what I got.